# UICollectionView cell fixed width and dynamic height using constraints in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints

I have one collectionview and a cell inside that which is having a fixed width and dynamic height based on its contents.I am using autolayout constraints , my code is below.

I have already tried to set all types of auto constraints inside the cell and inside the view .

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 5
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ViewControllerCell

            cell.lbl_text.text = "djs sdfs sdfs dsfsfd gdgfd dfgd df "

            return cell

        }



        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

            if let flowLayout = coll_main?.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
                flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize

            }



    }

In cell class method:
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = [UIView.AutoresizingMask.flexibleHeight]
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
```

i get cell width fix without i am set that width. how may this issue solve?

here screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have to implement `sizeForItemAt` to provide the correct size.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make sure that your `Estimate Size` is set to `None` for your CollectionView.

Answer (score 4):

Please do the following steps

1. Select your collectionView in interface builder.
2. Go to the size inspector
3. Change estimated size to none as shown in the image.

[image]

Hopefully it will fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

You can use collectionView delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width:, height:)
}
```

for this you need to extend `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and implement `sizeForItemAt` like following.

```
// MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout -
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let sectionInset = (collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout).sectionInset

        // Here you can set dynamic height for the individual cell according to your content size.
        let referenceHeight: CGFloat = 100 // Approximate height of your cell

        let referenceWidth = collectionView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame.width
            - sectionInset.left
            - sectionInset.right
            - collectionView.contentInset.left
            - collectionView.contentInset.right

        return CGSize(width: referenceWidth, height: referenceHeight)
    }
```

Here is an articale about it, you can follow [this](https://fewlinesofcode.com/swift,/uicollectionview/2018/11/01/uicollectionview-dynamic-cell-height.html).

Answer (score 0):

Add this property in your collection view or uncheck PrefetchingEnabled property in your nib.

`collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = false`

Answer (score 0):

Implement UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method for collection cell size.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

Then go to the storyboard and in size inspector make collectionView **Estimate size** to None